# How can I find the relative search path of a Framework added to a Swift iOS project using SPM?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have added a framework to my iOS project using SPM.  I would like to explicitly define the framework search path in an extension target Build Settings but I'm not sure how to find the relative search path.  The search path on my machine is:

/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-xxxxxxxxxxxx/SourcePackages/checkouts/amplify-ios

I can't add this as the search path as it's only relevant for my machine.  How can I find the search path relative to the project directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try to search /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-xxxxxxxxxxxx/SourcePackages/repositories/